# Searching dates within a Datatable returning no results

Tags: c#

I can’t seem to get any results back when searching a datetime column.

DateCreated field is saved as datetime type, within the mssql database.

```
// datatable
"data": "DateCreated", "name": "DateCreated",
                 render: function (data, type, row) {
                 return moment(data).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss A');
                }

//  code within controller
searchValue = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]").FirstOrDefault();

tAccounts = dbcontext.ApproveAccounts.Where(x => x.UserID.ToString().Contains(searchValue) || x.DateCreated.ToString().Contains(searchValue)).ToList();
```

Any pointers much appreciated.

Joe

Comment: Don't use "Contains" to search dates that are converted to string. You should be comparing dates as Dates. And, how likely is it that someone will have the hours, minutes and seconds that an account was created? Would you rather just search on a year/month/day?

Comment: can you provide an example of code how you should search for dates within this lamda?

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to parse the searchValue as a DateTime (adjust as needed per your culture and style). Then compare the `Dates` (eliminating time element). This assumes nothing will match `DateTime.MinValue` which is what you will get if parsing fails.

```
_ = DateTime.TryParse(searchValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime searchDt);

tAccounts = dbcontext.ApproveAccounts
    .Where(x => x.UserID.ToString().Contains(searchValue) || x.DateCreated.Date == searchDt.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: When I try to add x.DateCreated.Date I get error 'ApproveAccount' does not contain a definition for 'DateCreated' and no accessible extension method 'DateCreated' accepting a first argument of type 'ApproveAccount' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @JoeBlack I was basing this off of your question. There is not much I can add without knowing more about ApproveAccount.

Answer (score 0):

```
_ = DateTime.TryParse(searchValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime searchDt);

tAccounts = dbcontext.ApproveAccounts
    .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateAccountCreated) == searchDt.Date || x.UserID.ToString().Contains(searchValue)).ToList();
```